# In Drupal 7 Views, how can I display a block on every page of a view?

Tags: views

I am trying to display a [SimpleAds](http://drupal.org/project/simpleads) block for every page of my view. How can this be accomplished?

Clarification: I would like to display the block once for each page of results. I am using the infinite pager module.

Comment: Do you have a page view? You just activate the block from your blocks page. And assign the block to be visible for this page view url.

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

https://drupal.org/project/block_views

Also related:

[How can I show a block in a view page, excluding it's paginated pages](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/48819/how-can-i-show-a-block-in-a-view-page-excluding-its-paginated-pages/103623#comment50684_48840)

Answer (score 0):

So your view has a path, right? In the block configuration, at the bottom, where it says "Show block on specific pages, select "only the listed pages."

Then put your path in the box:
my-view-path/*

Or am I misunderstanding the question?