# How can I display a block on view page, excluding paginated/paged/pager output pages?

Tags: blocks, paging

I'm trying to use [Context](https://www.drupal.org/project/context) to display a block on a view page path, e.g. /view, but exclude it from the paged output, e.g. /view?page=1. The path exclusion tools in Drupal 8 don't work with the query string (and no query string rules are available).

There's a Drupal 7 solution (hack?) for this posted on [How can I show a block in a view page, excluding its paginated pages?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/48819/how-can-i-show-a-block-in-a-view-page-excluding-its-paginated-pages)

Any help to get something like this in Drupal 8 working would be appreciated.

The issue on Drupal.org is https://www.drupal.org/project/context/issues/2930896.

Comment: It's in early development (use at your own risk) but https://www.drupal.org/project/request_data_conditions has a url parameter condition that should get you what you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Clive's post above, this can be accomplished with the early dev module Request Data Conditions:

https://drupal.org/project/request_data_conditions

Comment: How to add in backend for /news?page=1;?