# Placing the Rocket Chat block on a page

Tags: 8, blocks

I'm trying to include a Drupal 8 Rocket Chat <strike>plugin</strike> module in my website. I installed the <strike>plugin</strike> module, set up a chat server, but I'm failing, of all places, at actually placing the block on a page (/chat). How do I do that? I'm completely new to Drupal.

Answer (score 1):

> - **install the livechat module** and rocket_chat module.
> - Setup the rocket_chat module.
> - Go to [Structure][Block layout]. there you can place the livechat block 
>     using the "Place block" button.
>     This works as a normal block we recommend you add it to a footer or alike 
>     for performance.

<sub>**Source:** Rocket chat module [README.md](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/rocket_chat/tree/README.md#n57)</sub>

In other words, go to `/admin/structure/block` find the Footer region and click on <kbd>Place block</kbd> search for "[RocketChat Livechat](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/rocket_chat/tree/modules/livechat/src/Plugin/Block/LiveChatBlock.php)" and click <kbd>Place block</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want the block on a specific page rather than all pages, so to build on No Sssweat's answer:

- Create a content page (of type "Static") and give it the `chat` path.
- In the block layout settings for the block you just placed, find the visibility options (see the screenshot in this question: [How can I show a block in a view page, excluding its paginated pages?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/48819/how-can-i-show-a-block-in-a-view-page-excluding-its-paginated-pages)) and set it to be shown only on `chat`.